# Java: how to "instanceof argument"

Tags: java, class, instanceof

I have tried:

```
package ro.ex;    

import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;

class Ex {
    public boolean isIns(Object o, Class t) {
        o instanceof t;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {}
}
```

above code will raise unknown class "t"

**My question is:** How to pass above code.

**update:**

following code can't pass intellij idea syntax checker

```
public boolean isIns(Object o, Class<?> t) {
    return o instanceof t;
}
```

so the right code in idea is:

```
public boolean isIns(Object o, Class<?> t) {
    return t.isAssignableFrom(o.getClass());
}
```

the more simple way is:

```
package ro.ex;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;

class Ex {
    public boolean isIns(Object o, Class t) {
        return t.isInstance(o);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Object r = new Ex().isIns("", String.class);
        System.out.println(r + "\t\t" + new Exception().getStackTrace()[0].getFileName() + ":" + new Exception().getStackTrace()[0].getLineNumber());
    }
}
```

Comment: How is this question related to Ruby?

Comment: I don't know about Java, but did you try: `public void IsIns<T>(Object o)` ? .You should specify a *Type*, not an instance

Comment: This is usually a sign of a bad design that defeats the purpose of polymorphism.  Look into generics or learn how to do polymorphism.  Shouldn't that method return a boolean instead of void?

Comment: Well u can check out the method of object in core java u can get idea from that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you write `x instanceof t`, then `t` must be a class. In your `isIns` method, `t` is not a class, it is a variable of type `Class`.

The class `Class`, however, does offer methods with which you can decide whether some other class is a subclass of it: `Class.isAssignableFrom(Class)`. So you can change you method to:

```
public boolean isIns(Object o, Class t)
{
    return t.isAssignableFrom(o.getClass());
}
```

(I also changed your code so that the result of is returned to the caller.)

Comment: Note to OP: if you use `isInstance()` instead, then you don't need to null-check `o`.

Comment: Make it `Class<?> t` , if you don't want to get the unchecked call Warning in AndroidStudio

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what you are trying to do with your method, but the **instanceof** syntax is wrong.

```
 public boolean isIns(Object o, Class t) {
       return  o instanceof t;
    }
```

`instanceof` keyword checks with a Valid class name not with variable name. That's the compiler error.

For ex : `o instanceof String`, if you write like below, it won't compile

```
public boolean isIns(Object o, String str) {
        return o instanceof str;  //err, o instance of String is correct way to check.
    }
```

And I slightly changed your method signature to match the statement.

Comment: Also, why would you create such a method? Isn't it easier to use the prebuilt `instanceof` ?

Comment: Should probably add a "return" keyword here or there. :)

Comment: @Henrik Not concentrated on whole body. Just guiding for syntax of `instanceof` :). Done!.

Answer (score 0):

In your code below, `t` should be the name of a Java class (e.g. `String`). In your code, you've passed a variable name which is not appropriate:

```
public void isIns(Object o, Class t) {
    o instanceof t;
}
```

Since an `instanceof` check is a one-liner, I'm not sure why you are wrapping it in a method. But if you insist on doing so, perhaps this is what you want:

```
public static boolean isIns(Object o, Class<?> t) {
  return c.isInstance(o);
}
```

But two notes:

1. Lots of `instanceof` checks generally indicate bad design.
2. A Java programmer will be much more comfortable seeing `instanceof` rather than `isIns(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the dinamic equivalent of instanceof from Class class.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isInstance(java.lang.Object)

```
  public void isIns(Object o, Class t) {
        t.isInstance(o);
  }
```

Check for nulls if needed.

Answer (score -1):

maybe you want something like this?

```
public class test2 {

    class c {
    }

    public test2() {
        c obj = new c();
        System.out.println(isIns(obj));
    }

    public boolean isIns(Object o) {
        return (o instanceof c);
    }

    public static void main(String argv[]) {
        new test2();
    }
}
```

EDIT: Removed senceless Class parameters.

Comment: this does compile. at least with my eclipse.

Comment: Oh, I see. Well, it may compile if you include all of your code, but it's still a poor example. Why accept an argument `Class<?> c` if you are going to ignore it? That was the source of my confusion.

Comment: well, i still cant figure out what he was asking for. Just tried to make a better working copy of it. This all seems pretty senceless. But you are right, my example is bad. Gonna edit it.

Comment: @Duncan What i really wonder: why are you using Class<?> in your example? That is very strange, since you also dont use it. (cant commit under your answer because of mssing 50 reputation)